# ABC Puzzle- Constraint Satisfaction Problem

Tags: python, constraints, artificial-intelligence, constraint-programming, discrete-optimization

ABC is a logic puzzle on a board 5x5. In each row and column, there has to be exactly 3 letters(A,B,C) and 2 empty cells. Additionally for each row and column there is information about which is the first letter in that row/column. That does not mean that is the letter in the first cell, but the first letter in the row(There can be empty spaces before the first letter). [This](https://ibb.co/wY62kZG) is the board with its information.

**I need help figuring out the constraint for the first letter in each row and column.**

I already have the constraint for each row and column but just cannot figure out how to find the exact place for the first letter in a row or column.
This is what i have so far.

*Note i used 1,2,3 for A,B,C and i used "_"(Single space) and "__"(Double space) for the empty cells, in order to still stay within the 'AllDifferentConstraint'.

```
from constraint import *

if __name__ == "__main__":

problem = Problem(BacktrackingSolver())

variables = []
for i in range(0, 25):
    variables.append(i)
domain= []
for i in range(1,4):
    domain.append(i)

domain.append("_")
domain.append("__")

problem.addVariables(variables, domain)

for row in range(5):
    problem.addConstraint(AllDifferentConstraint(), [row * 5 + i for i in range(5)])

for col in range(5):
    problem.addConstraint(AllDifferentConstraint(), [col * 5 + i for i in range(5)])


solution = problem.getSolution()
print(solution)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Disclaimer:**

- my code might look slightly over-engineered
- for someone doing lots of CP stuff recently, the available set of constraints of this library look strange and/or incomplete (compared to industrial-strength [Gecode](https://www.gecode.org/))

  - i consider this solution a hack (but it's enough for this toy-problem)
- i kept most of your code, but changed the spaces to numbers (8, 9) for better visualization

**Basic idea**
Assuming the dimensions are fixed a-priori, there are exactly 5 valid cases for the constraint you seek, when looking from the **front of the slice**:

```
0: _  __ TARGET ...dontcare
1: __ _  TARGET ...dontcare
2: _  TARGET    ...dontcare
3: __ TARGET    ...dontcare
4: TARGET       ...dontcare
```

As someone coming from SAT-solving (before CP), i feel reasoning with *clauses* pretty natural. The above is easily expressed in boolean-logic (not same order as above):

```
   (  pos0 = F                  )
OR ( (pos0 = _ )  and (pos1 = F) )
OR ( (pos0 = __)  and (pos1 = F) )
OR ( (pos0 = __) and (pos1 = _  ) and (pos2 = F)
OR ( (pos0 = _ )  and (pos1 = __ ) and (pos2 = F)
```

Normally one would use a well-implemented constraint / propagator (using SAT technology), but this library is missing the usual stuff.

**But to our rescue: there is [FunctionConstraint](http://labix.org/doc/constraint/public/constraint.FunctionConstraint-class.html)** which allows us to build a simple propagator. This is actually quite a nice design (for small and relatively easy problems)!

Some remarks:

- `clause` builds our boolean-logic based propagator (in non-efficient manner)
- `row` and `clause` returns the 1d-indices based on what we want
- `reverse` let's us reuse the logic when the constraint needs to act from the end (and not on the front)
- we use *partial function application* to make the calls compact
- numpy is just used as quick visualization-tool (there is nothing worse than reasoning about matrix-solutions from a *dict*)

**Code**

```
""" ORIGINAL CODE """

from constraint import *

problem = Problem(BacktrackingSolver())

variables = []
for i in range(0, 25):
    variables.append(i)
domain= []
for i in range(1,4):
    domain.append(i)

domain.append(8)
domain.append(9)

problem.addVariables(variables, domain)

for row in range(5):
    problem.addConstraint(AllDifferentConstraint(), [row * 5 + i for i in range(5)])

for col in range(5):
    problem.addConstraint(AllDifferentConstraint(), [col * 5 + i for i in range(5)])

""" ADDITIONS """

from functools import partial  

def clause(target, p0, p1, p2, p3, p4):
  wildcards = [8, 9]
  return (p0 == target) or                                              \
        ( (p0 in wildcards) and (p1 == target) ) or                    \
        ( (p0 in wildcards) and (p1 in wildcards) and p2 == target ) 


row = lambda x: [x * 5 + i for i in range(5)]
col = lambda x: [x + i * 5 for i in range(5)]
reverse = lambda x: list(reversed(x))

problem.addConstraint(partial(clause, 3), reverse(row(0))) # C
problem.addConstraint(partial(clause, 2), reverse(row(1))) # B
problem.addConstraint(partial(clause, 3), reverse(row(2))) # C
problem.addConstraint(partial(clause, 1), row(2))          # A
problem.addConstraint(partial(clause, 2), row(3))          # B
problem.addConstraint(partial(clause, 1), col(0))          # A
problem.addConstraint(partial(clause, 2), col(1))          # B
problem.addConstraint(partial(clause, 1), col(3))          # A
problem.addConstraint(partial(clause, 3), reverse(col(0))) # C
problem.addConstraint(partial(clause, 3), reverse(col(2))) # C
problem.addConstraint(partial(clause, 3), reverse(col(3))) # C

""" SOLVE """

solution = problem.getSolution()
print(solution)

""" VISUALIZE """

import numpy as np
matrix = np.zeros((5, 5), dtype=int)
matrix[np.unravel_index(range(5*5), (5,5))] = [solution[i] for i in range(5*5)]
print(matrix)
```

**Output**

```
λ python C:\Tmp\constr.py
{10: 9, 13: 3, 11: 1, 12: 2, 0: 9, 3: 1, 5: 1, 8: 2, 15: 9, 18: 8, 14: 8, 20: 3, 23: 9, 1: 2, 2: 8, 6: 9, 7: 3, 16: 2, 17: 3, 4: 3, 9: 8, 19: 1, 22: 8, 21: 2, 24: 1}

[[9 2 8 1 3]
 [1 9 3 2 8]
 [9 1 2 3 8]
 [9 2 3 8 1]
 [3 2 8 9 1]]
```

The result surprisingly looks correct ;-), comparing with your original task:

[image]